# Enviar dos datos a una vista

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo que mandar dos datos a mi vista

Llenar el input

```
$this->load->model("User_model");
$productos = $this->User_model->getUsers();
$datos['productos'] = $productos;
```

traer los datos de la base para llenar la base

```
$datos = array("data"=>$this->Attendance_model->getUsers());
$this->load->view('attendance/main',$datos);
```

Si a los dos datos que deseo mandar les pongo el mismo nombre el input no lo manda, pero si cambio de nombre solo me manda uno de los dos datos.

Espero me puedan a ayudar para saber como mandar, ya que necesito llenar el input para filtrar los datos de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar más de 1 parámetro lo puedes hacer muy similar a como lo tienes actualmente, con la diferencia que tienes que definir un índice.

Por ejemplo:

```
public function tufunction()
{
    $data['primerdato'] = 'Primer valor';
    $data['segundodato'] = 'Segundo valor';
    $data['soyunarray'] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    $this->load->view('attendance/main', $data);
}
```

Con esto ya estarías pasando 3 variables a tu vista y dentro de tu vista las puedes imprimir con `$primerdato` o `$segundodato`. Al igual si lo que estás pasando a la vista un **array** lo recorres con un `foreach()`.

```
<?php foreach($soyunarray as $a) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $a; ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Para más información te recomiendo visitar la documentación oficial de [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) en el área de [Views](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html).